# Geocoding Addresses

Tags: geocoding

I'm using civiCRM 4.6.2.

I've configured the system for the use of geocoding. I'm using google maps and have an API key. When I run geocoding for parsing (ie parse = 1 and geocode  = 0) the addresses are parsed correctly.

When I then run for geocoding my addresses (parse = 0 and geocode = 1) I always get back 0 addresses were processed. If I go into a contact and save their address the lat and long is created. I have throttle set to 1.

I've tried with a large set of addresses (start = 1000 and end = 2000) and with smaller sets, down to even just one address. I've dumped my contacts to make sure that the start and end represent valid contact IDs.

Any thoughts on how to get geocoding to work for me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found that if contacts have a geocode even if it's wrong, it won't update it.

You can get this situation if you import updates to addresses (like from NCOA) and don't have the import do the geocoding, which I think is the default.  (Really this is a bug and I'll file an issue on it when I have a free min.)

I ended up using sql to zero out the codes.

Comment: Thank you! I checked and the contacts don't have the lat/long. Would love to use sql but need the actual lat/long :) Thank you for filing an issue on it! When we enter new contacts, we get the lat/long, so we'll just work through the other contacts until it's fixed. Appreciate the quick response!

Comment: You might also try Yahoo for geocoding and see if that works; though, it seems like if it works for manually adding/changing one, it should work for bulk.    I assume you looked in the logs for errors and tried turning on logging to see if any errors get trapped.

Comment: Is there anyway to have it skip contacts who already have the geocode?

Comment: I think it skips contacts with geocodes by default.  It doesn't update ones that are incorrect.